# SASL Enabled Memcached LIST_MECH return empty supported mechanisms

Tags: configuration, memcached, sasl

I am writing my own implementation of a memcachedClient within which I want to add authentication. I just started with PLAIN auth but failed. In short, the LIST_MECH command always returns an empty result, if I go ahead and issue and PLAIN AUTH command, it says,

```sh
mech:  ``PLAIN'' with 34 bytes of data
SASL (severity 2): Couldn't find mech PLAIN
```

Below is my configuration:

- I am on memcache 1.5.12
- My memcached.conf

```sh
% cat memcached.conf
mech_list: plain
log_level: 5
sasldb_path: /tmp/memcached-sasl-db
```

- My /tmp/memcached-sasl-db

```sh
% cat memcached-sasl-db
myname:mypass
```

- My exports:

```sh
export MEMCACHED_SASL_PWDB=/tmp/memcached-sasl-db
export SASL_CONF_PATH=`pwd`/memcached.conf
```

Upon launching:

```sh
./memcached -m 32 -S -B binary -vvvv
Reading configuration from: </MemcachedBuildDirection/build/bin/>
Initialized SASL.
```

The LIST_MECH is showing:

```sh
<29 Read binary protocol data:
<29    0x80 0x20 0x00 0x00
<29    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<29    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<29    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
<29    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<29    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
authenticated() in cmd 0x20 is true
>29 Writing bin response:
>29   0x81 0x20 0x00 0x00
>29   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
>29   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
>29   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
>29   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
>29   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

It shows that the response has a total length of zero. Thus I am reading an empty list from the output.

And the AUTH command:

```sh
<29 Read binary protocol data:
<29    0x80 0x21 0x00 0x05
<29    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<29    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x27
<29    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
<29    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<29    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
authenticated() in cmd 0x21 is true
29: going from conn_parse_cmd to conn_nread
mech:  ``PLAIN'' with 34 bytes of data
SASL (severity 2): Couldn't find mech PLAIN
sasl result code:  -4
Unknown sasl response:  -4
>29 Writing an error: Auth failure.
>29 Writing bin response:
>29   0x81 0x21 0x00 0x00
>29   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x20
>29   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0d
>29   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
>29   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
>29   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

I expect there will be a list of supported auth mechs being returned by LIST_MECH.

Can anyone here point me at some direction that could make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this our by myself. The Cyrus-SASL was not installed correctly in my workspace.

Usually you could install sasl by `sudo yum install cyrus-sasl-devel` this works for me.

Sometimes, the package management framework you are working with do no let you use `yum` to install dependencies but through some certain dependency management tool. Then you have to figure it out from there. In my case, I have to specify `SASL_PATH` as an environment variable and point it to where my dependency management tool installed the SASL shared library.